# Remove HTML Tags from a std::string

Tags: c++

How would I remove all HTML tags while the string is a 'std::string'.
Input: `<b>Blah blah blah</b>`
Expected output after HTML tags stripped should be: `Blah blah blah`

Comment: This is request for code and not a question.

Comment: Just remove first 3 characters and last 4 characters.

Comment: @Richard Critten, so don't give him code but an idea how to write it by himself. He might be new and c++ isn't an easy language for newbies.

Comment: @Detonar I agree with Richard. Such questions are not good fit for SO format.

Comment: I wrote a rather long and detailed answer to this, that covered a lot of bases - but the question was put on hold in the meantime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [std::string::find()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/) to search for `<` and `>` then use [std::string::replace](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/replace/) to replace them and the content within with an empty string `""`.

Repeat this in a loop until find() returns std::npos, which indicates that the searched character couldn't be found.